# Build project targeting for both x86 and x64 platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, x86-64, projects-and-solutions

In my solution, there is a class library which is an excel add-in. When I build the solution or that project, I want this project will be built firstly targeting for x86 with outputing a file named `xxx.dll`, and then targeting for x64 with outputing a file named `xxx_x64.dll`.

How should I do for this, or how could I edit the csproj file? Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem.  The C# compiler generates MSIL, it runs on any architecture.  Getting the DLL deployed requires registering it with Regasm.exe so Excel can find it back.  There are two versions of it, 32-bit and 64-bit.  If you don't know anything about the flavor of Office that the user has installed then simply run both versions of it.  Using the same DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved this problem by using Shared Project in Visual Studio. What I want is two Excel Addin assemblies will be generated by building the solution, one is targeting to `x86` platform or `AnyCPU`, the other is targeting to `x64` platform.

Here is my projects snapshot:

[image]

All the code files(*.cs) and resources(images or xml files) are moved into the Shared project, and both the other 2 projects have a reference to it.

As to the other 2 projects, there are some differences between them, e.g. Assembly Name and Target Platform. One is `XXX.dll` and targeting `AnyCPU`, the other is `XXX_64.dll` and targeting `x64`.

When building the solution, each of the 2 projects will issue the corresponding assembly.

Answer (score 2):

> How should I do for this, or how could I edit the csproj file?

The name of assembly xxx.dll is defined by the property `AssemblyName` in the project file, if you want to change the default output assembly named with platform, you can simple change the value of this property with following code in the project file `.csproj`:

```
<AssemblyName>TestWithDllWithPlatform_$(Platform)</AssemblyName>
```

But with this setting, you will get the output assembly named `xxx_x86.dll` when you targeting for x86.

If you still want targeting for x86 with outputing a file named `xxx.dll` rather than `xxx_x86.dll`, you can try to rename the dll file with post-build event when you targeting for `x64`:

```
if $(Platform) == x64 (copy /y "$(TargetPath)" "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(TargetName)_$(Platform).dll")
```

In this case, when you targeting `x64`, outputing assembly named would be `xxx_x64.dll`:

[image]

Besides, if you do not want keep the original `xxx_.dll`, you can delete it with below command in the post-build:

```
if $(Platform) == x64 (del "$(TargetPath)")
```

Hope this helps.